# Lenovo Z570 Laptop cutting sound when tilted

Tags: windows-7, audio, shutdown, lenovo-laptop

I currently have a Lenovo Z570 laptop, as said in the title. 
I like to have it on my knees while sitting on the couch, or laid in my bed. 
The thing is, when I try to move a bit, it tilts the laptop and the sound cuts off... The "cut sound" touch button doesn't work in this case, so I have to pause the movie/music and go into the sound manager to put the sound back on. I have the same problem while moving the screen, though it seems to be quite random. I do not know how it works, and I've tried many ways to narrow the solutions dow, to understand how it happens, never understood it completely.
I have tried once to uninstall completely the hard drive, I've cleaned it up all the way, reinstalled Windows 7 x64, reinstalled all my programs and drivers directly from Lenovo's website, but it still happens... Grr.
Could someone help me, or do somebody have the same problem as I do?
Thx!

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer you wanted, but I am guessing you have a hardware issue.  Since it happens when you move the computer, I am going to venture to say that you have a loose connection to something.  Unfortunately, you probably will have to take the computer apart to figure out if that is the problem.  (I would let a PC repairman do it, unless you know how.)

Good luck!